# asp.net page not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I started learning asp.net (I think the webpages not webforms, razor thingy? :) )

Ok I'm a complete noob, but anyway, I've been looking online and I've seen this question asked multiple times but none of the answers are helping me. I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) and I'm trying to do what its saying but when I run the code.cshtml it just displays the code in a webpage... I know there's gotta be some setting I have to fix or something but I don't know where that is.

my question is, how do I get a web browser to display an x.cshtml file? (I'm using microsoft visual web developer, but I also tried it using notepad and uploading the file to my website, still no good)

I forgot to add, using visual web developer gives me the following errors and wont run:

Error   1   Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Error   2   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Error   3   Identifier expected line 8

heres the code

```
@
{
    var total = 0;
    var totalMessage = "";
    if(IsPost) {

        // Retrieve the numbers that the user entered.
        var num1 = Request["text1"];
        var num2 = Request["text2"];

        // Convert the entered strings into integers numbers and add.
        total = num1.AsInt() + num2.AsInt();
        totalMessage = "Total = " + total;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Add Numbers</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {background-color: beige; font-family: Verdana, Arial;
            margin: 50px; }
      form {padding: 10px; border-style: solid; width: 250px;}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <p>Enter two whole numbers and then click <strong>Add</strong>.</p>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p><label for="text1">First Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text1" />
    </p>
    <p><label for="text2">Second Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text2" />
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
  </form>

  <p>@totalMessage</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with WebPages, Not MVC. The simplest way to develope webpages is to have WebMatrix.

[Check out this tutorial to get started with WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started)

When it comes to your code, I only see one mistake i.e, **@{** they should some side by side. Other than that everything is working good.

To run your cshtml in browser, please refer to the link I shared at top, that is clearly showing how to run the page in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think your immediate problem is that you cannot have a linebreak after the '@' character in razor.  Try @{ then linebreak...